# How to set height of TextFormfield in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, desktop-application

First, Recently I have started to building desktop app with dart code.
just built some screens and which are responsible for mobile and web too, for that used `LayoutBuilder`
but going wrong with when trying to set the height according to mine, for that I wrapped  `TextformField` with `Container` and gave height.

when I put validation on `TextformField` onClick of login button then something goes wrong with the height of  `TextformField`.

Look at the Screenshot:
before of click the login button:

[image]

When I click the login button without inputting any value for checking validation:
[image]

Piece of code of `TextformField` :

```
Widget _buildEmailTextField() {
   return Container(
     height: 35,
     child: Theme(
       data: new ThemeData(
         primaryColor: Color(0xFF262C48),
         primaryColorDark: Color(0xFF262C48),
       ),
       child: TextFormField(
         keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
         validator: (val){
           bool emailValid = RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+")
           .hasMatch(val);
           if(!emailValid){
           return 'Invalid Email Address';
           }else{
             return null;
           }
         },
         controller: emailController,
         readOnly: isLoading?true:false,
         decoration: InputDecoration(
           fillColor:  Color(0xFFd9d8d8),
           filled: true,
           
           border: new OutlineInputBorder(
             borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
               const Radius.circular(7.0),
             ),
             borderSide: BorderSide(color:Color(0xFF262C48),width: 2.0)
           ),
           contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
           // prefixIcon: Icon(
           //   Icons.email,
           //   color: Color(0xFF008577),
           // ),
           hintText: 'Email',
           
         ),
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
```

Comment: use `SizeBox`  instead of` `Container`

Comment: as you suggested, I tried but getting same issue.

Comment: What's the height you are using in SizeBox ?

Comment: used fixed size 35

Comment: No increase with 45 or 55 and try again

Comment: I implemented but the height textFormFiled is too high, I used container to reduce the size of TextField.

Answer (score 3):

`TextFormField` inherits size from child. One of solution is to set `contentPadding` in `InputDecoration`.
You already use this to pad left side. You can do modification like below:

```dart
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 15.0, bottom: 15.0),
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check it out,

```
Widget _buildEmailTextField()) {
    return Container(
        height: 35,
        child: Theme(
          data: new ThemeData(
            primaryColor: Color(0xFF262C48),
            primaryColorDark: Color(0xFF262C48),
          ),
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Container(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    validator: (val) {
                      bool emailValid = RegExp(
                              r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+")
                          .hasMatch(val);
                      if (!emailValid) {
                        return 'Invalid Email Address';
                      } else {
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
                    controller: emailController,
                    readOnly: isLoading ? true : false,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      fillColor: Color(0xFFd9d8d8),
                      filled: true,

                      border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                            const Radius.circular(7.0),
                          ),
                          borderSide:
                              BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF262C48), width: 2.0)),
                      contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 25.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                      // prefixIcon: Icon(
                      //   Icons.email,
                      //   color: Color(0xFF008577),
                      // ),
                      hintText: 'Email',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    // Validate returns true if the form is valid, otherwise false.
                    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                      // If the form is valid, display a snackbar. In the real world,
                      // you'd often call a server or save the information in a database.

                      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')));
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text('Submit'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
```

Comment: Can you send me screenshot?